# Can anyone identify a font roughly equivilant to the style in this 14th centuary document

Tags: font-identification

I'd like to find a close approximation to the font in the following historical document:

[image]

I realise of course that it is hand written -- but I have seen in the past "handwritten" calligraphic style fonts produce from some historical source e.g. P22 Da Vinci.

I've tried font identification tools Whatthefont etc. and a very very good piece of software called "find my font" (it's very good), but as the image is poor and the text hand written, nothing comes up.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **Chancery Typography**. Try making a specific search at a font site using "chancery", like:

[Chancery fonts at fontspace.com](https://www.fontspace.com/category/chancery)

[Chancery fonts at 1001fonts.com](https://www.1001fonts.com/search.html?search=chancery&x=0&y=0)

[Chancery fonts at myfonts.com](https://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3Achancery/fonts/)

Comment: So you actually got me closer in a sense! I don't think these two suggestions are very close to the source in my original question. BUT your Chancery suggestion got me to something called Chancery Hand -- which is very very close!!!

Comment: @QuantumPenguin: I think you might want to try Chancellerie - I think it's a *bit* closer to the specific letterforms of the hand in your image and the font has a slightly bled over time inked feel which really helps. https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/glc/1648-chancellerie/